# Python - I want to use a BST for tag indexing and searching. What packages should I be looking at?

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

I want to be able to find a node in the BST for the search term (or the closest match) and return not just the exact match but also the children of that node. e.g. I can search for "cat" and also find "catalog" and "cataracts", or get "car" and "camp" when no keys with the prefix "cat" exist in the tree. Having a lot of experience just using my own implementations I've come to take this quirk of BSTs for granted. Is there a Python package that exposes this functionality, or that would be easy to modify to suit my needs? Would be nice if I didn't have to write my own. Ideally the tree would be balanced. Thanks!

Comment: Library-shopping questions don't fit with Stack Overflow, which is geared to the idea of there being one right answer, not a discussion or a set of partial answers. [Software Recs](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) may be better, but in general a mailing list, forum, etc. is probably the best way to get recommendations and discussions going.

Comment: However, if you search PyPI, you should find multiple examples. I've used `bintrees` with no complaints, and I've played with `rbtree` and a few others. There are also a variety of modified-B-tree libraries like `sortedcontainers` and `blist`, and various implementations of tries and skiplists and all kinds of other logarithmic data types. (In fact, a trie might be closer to what you want than a BST here…)

Comment: I did a little shopping around and hit a wall for the node exposure, hence why I tried here. Sorry if it's not a good fit.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You might be better served looking at a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie which allows for the sort nearest match functionality that you are after.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/marisa-trie or  https://pythonhosted.org/PyTrie/ would be two examples.

Comment: I probably should've been expecting to use a trie in the first place - thanks much for the answer, and for the examples.